# how to pass multiple input files through 'for' command

Tags: bash

I have multiple samples with R1 and R2 reads in fastq.gz format (these files are complementary to  each other) I want to run BWA mem paired end parallel on all the files once finished each R1 and R2 complementary file should produce one sam file. Right now I am making two sam file from the two reads

This is what I have come up with but it’s not doing what I need it to do

```
for i in `find -maxdepth 2 -iname *fastq.gz -type f`; do
   echo "bwa mem -t 12 /H.Sapiens/ucsc.hg19.fasta  ${i}_R1_001.fastq.gz  ${i}_R2_001.fastq.gz > ${i}_R1_R2.sam"
done
```

when it runs it looks like this

```
bwa mem -t 12 /H.Sapiens/ucsc.hg19.fasta  ./Sample_0747/0747_CGG_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz_R1_001.fastq.gz ./Sample_0747/0747_CGG_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz_R2_001.fastq.gz > ./Sample_0747/0747_CGG_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz_R1_R2.sam

bwa mem -t 12 H.Sapiens/ucsc.hg19.fasta  ./Sample_0748/0748_CCA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz_R1_001.fastq.gz ./Sample_0748/0748_CCA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz_R2_001.fastq.gz > ./Sample_0748/0748_CCA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz_R1_R2.sam
-bash-4.1$
```

I understand the problem is in iname but how do I fixit?
Thank you so much

Comment: as you can see, two different answers. So, you could add the `wanted output` example... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find -maxdepth 2 -iname \*fastq.gz -type f |
sed 's/_R[12]_001\.fastq\.gz$//' |
sort -u | 
while IFS= read -r f; do
   echo "bwa mem -t 12 /H.Sapiens/ucsc.hg19.fasta \"${f}_R1_001.fastq.gz\"  \"${f}_R2_001.fastq.gz\" > \"${f}_R1_R2.sam\""
done
```

Answer (score 1):

[Don't loop over a value parsed like that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)*. First, put your code in a script for sanity's sake, like

```
cat > script < SCRIPT
  for i; do
    bwa mem -t 12 /H.Sapiens/ucsc.hg19.fasta "${i}_R"{1,2}_001.fastq.gz > "${i}_R1_R2.sam"
  done
SCRIPT
chmod +x script
```

Then, either use the `-exec` predicate, or `xargs`, like

```
find -maxdepth 2 -iname '*fastq.gz' -type f -exec ./script {} +
```

or

```
find -maxdepth 2 -iname '*fastq.gz' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ./script
```

*It says "parsing `ls`", but it applies to parsing any command meant for human consumption. `find` is expressly called out.

---

On another note, if you don't put quotes around your arguments to `find`, the shell may interpret them as globs.

```
find -iname *fastq.gz
```

could expand to

```
find -iname foofastq.gz barfastq.gz bazfastq.gz
```

You want

```
find -iname '*fastq.gz'
```